# JWT Token [Object Object]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have a JWT authorizing system. When I login i put JWT token from server into local storage.

Also I have `TariffsApiComponent` which calls `getTariffs` thunk in `TariffsReducer`.

This thunk makes get http request for tariffs using this JWT token in headers, but then when I check the response from server I don`t get resultCode = 0 (successful request).

I tried to check what`s wrong with my token on server but there I see this.

Also Have to say that if I reload the page not deleting the token from local storage It is working!

### Component

```
TariffsContainer.jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Tariffs from "./Tariffs";
import { changeTariffStatus, getTariffs } from "../../../redux/tariffsReducer";
import withAuthRedirect from "../../../hoc/withAuthRedirect";
import { compose } from "redux";

class TariffsApiComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTariffs();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tariffs
        tariffId={this.props.tariffId}
        tariffs={this.props.tariffs}
        changeTariffStatus={this.props.changeTariffStatus}
      />
    );
  }
}
...

tariffsReducer.js
...
export const setTariffs = (tariffs, tariffId) => ({
  type: SET_TARIFFS,
  tariffs,
  tariffId
});

export const getTariffs = () => dispatch => {
  getTariffsAPI().then(response => {
    if (response.resultCode === 0) {
      let { tariffs, tariffId } = response;
      dispatch(setTariffs(tariffs, tariffId));
    }
  });
};
...
```

### requests

```
...
const instance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
  }
});

export const getTariffsAPI = () => {
  return instance
    .get(`http://localhost:1337/tariffs`)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data.data});
};
...
```

### middleware

```
let checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers["x-access-token"] || req.headers["authorization"];
    if (token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        token = token.slice(7, token.length);
    }

    console.log(req.headers["x-access-token"]);

    if (token) {

        jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Token is not valid"
                });
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Auth token is not supplied"
        });
    }
};
```

### Error

[image]

what I see on server after login

[image]

Comment: What does it display if you add console.log(response) to getTariffsAPI().then(response => {console.log(response);

Comment: https://imgur.com/21mntgv . and access token there in request https://imgur.com/4HaalwK

Comment: If the log isn't giving you clear outputs, then maybe you can try `JSON.Stringify` the object to see what it is.

Comment: https://imgur.com/LVsh4ak   empty object, but Why if i set it here https://imgur.com/dp7okD6

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem occurs, but can`t get why axios create isn`t working.
Commented one - not working. Not commented - working.

[Axios create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POygs.png)

[Commented one and not commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay74F.png)

Comment: Seems like your instance got created before login, when token is null or invalid in localstorage.On reload instance creation code is invoked again, this time localstorage has correct token.

Comment: Okay, got it, don`t you know a good option to solve this problem not adding headers to request every time?

Comment: Use axios interceptors. https://gist.github.com/srph/38f67a10e991b6cb2d83